# Simplest CSS equivalent for two-column one-row table?

Tags: html, css

What is the simplest CSS equivalent for this HTML code:

```
<table><tr><td>
One<br>
Two
</td><td>
Three<br>
Four
</td></tr></table>
```

Background:

I've been asked to modify an existing website that uses CSS extensively.  My knowledge of CSS is rudimentary at best, but the changes being requested were fairly straightforward, mainly just text edits.  However, one edit involved adding a bullet list that was too long to fit in its assigned area.  I decided to use a table to break it into two lists, but when I input a rudimentary HTML table, it was offset downwards by several lines and displayed in a different font than the rest of the paragraph.  So, is there a way I can make a "table" with CSS that will inherit all the properties of the area (or is DIV the correct term) that it is in?

Comment: Unless you are displaying tabular data, don't use a table!  This isn't 1995.  For a bullet list consider `<ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like the example below.

`display: flex` will align children items side-by-side. By applying `flex-grow: 1` to these children, they will grow to equal widths to fit the parent container.

We can also use `<ul>` for an unordered list, with each `<li>` representing a bulleted item.

The result is essentially identical to a single-row, two-column table, with a list in either cell.

```css
.table-div {
    display: flex;
}

.table-div > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-div">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dropped the following code into my webpage, but it displayed the first two lines as text, and the lists were in the wrong place and using the wrong font.  Did I do something incorrect?

.table-div { display: flex; }
.table-div > div { flex-grow: 1; }
<div class='table-div'>
 <div>
  <ul>
   <li>One
   <li>Two
   <li>Three
   <li>Four
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div>
  <ul>
   <li>Five
   <li>Six
   <li>Seven
   <li>Eight
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: Do the two ".table-div" statements need to go somewhere other than immediately before the "div class" statement?

Comment: The HTML portion needs to go in your `<body>` section. The first section, `.table-div { ... }` etc, is CSS, and needs to be separated. You can either put it in a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` section of your page, or you can create a new text file for it, save it as a *.css* file, and reference it in the `<head>` section using a `<link>`. [Basic example of CSS styles in <head>](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp)
 **|** [Basic example of using an external CSS file using <link>](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Unfortunately, even when I put the two .table-div lines between <style> and </style> tags in my <head> section, the "table" itself is still not inheriting the font characteristics from the text immediately preceding.  It's still in a different font and displaced downwards and to the left.  There's something else going on, some sort of CSS side-effect or interaction.

Comment: Well unfortunately, without providing a way for us to replicate the issue you're having, I don't know how much better of a solution you're going to get. Try right clicking on the table and going to "Inspect Element" to see what classes/styles are affecting it. Additionally, the `div` won't inherit the style from the preceding element unless they share a parent, or a style.

Comment: Progress.  Adding this code in my header gives me the font and placement I need: <style>
.table-div {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 80px;
}
</style>  The only problem I have now is that my columns are too narrow, with too much space between them.  Any suggestions as to what I should add to make the two columns wider?  And, again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like I've posted below. You can then just adjust the widths to be how you would need them to be.

```css
#table {
  width: 600px;
}

#table ul {
  width: 50%;
}

#table ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the "simplest" I could get. Using flexbox's [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) and [`flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) properties, you can make the single "column" of an unordered list bridge two columns. You'll need to adjust the `max-height` of the `ul` and the `width` of the `li`s to ensure the values wrap the way you want them to.

```css
.table-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-indent: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 3rem;
}

.table-list li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="table-list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```